# Elegant way to replace a single record on a very small table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a small table with only a few records (~20) that I'm using as cache for a really expensive query that returns an array of strings. The table contains a single text column and it will be updated every few minutes. The array is updated in memory and most of the time only one of the records is changed.

I'm thinking of using a transaction with something like:

```
INSERT INTO cache(id)
SELECT unnest($1::text[])
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

DELETE FROM cache
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT unnest($1::text[]))
```

but I have a feeling that I might as well just delete everything and then insert it again since it's such a small table. Another option would be to try and combine the queries with a CTE or something. What's the best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think this will outperform the optimiser?

Comment: As the table is so tiny, yes, [truncate](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_drop_table.asp) and insert.

Comment: Generally, you're always better to *replace* rather than *update* because applying deltas is brittle to the previous state which can lead to drifting away from its proper state. With delete-replace paradigm previous state is irrelevant so you have 100% confidence of end state.